# same codes but are not working one of two?

Tags: php, oop

You will have to [get.class.php](http://pastebin.com/ZZufCVU6) for giving help.

Working case(index.php spaghetti):

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/get.class.php';
$get = new Get();
$get->getSql("SELECT * FROM gunler ORDER BY g_id ASC LIMIT 0,15");
foreach($get->getData() as $data)
{
    echo $data["g_name"];
}
?>
```

result of spaghetti:

```
18 January 2012
```

the successful in a sense.

Are not working case:

```
<?php
require_once 'get.class.php';

Class Main Extends Get
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // boş
    }

    public function getGun($limit = 15, $sayfa = 1)
    {
        $limit1 = $limit * ($sayfa - 1);
        $limit2 = $limit1 + $limit;
        parent::getSql("SELECT * FROM gunler ORDER BY g_id ASC LIMIT " . $limit1 . "," . $limit2);
        return parent::getData();
    }
}

?>
$main = new Main();

print_r($main->getGun());
```

result of this:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in C:\AppServ\www\dailypremium\classes\get.class.php on line 39

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in C:\AppServ\www\dailypremium\classes\get.class.php on line 55
Array ( )
```

I can't see any difference first codes between second codes. Where is the problem?

Comment: Tried adding `parent::__construct()` in your Main::__construct() ?

Comment: That's the error you get when you've not established the mysql connection properly - or are accidentally supplying a null (non mysql connection) value to your mysql query functions. It's hard to say more without the code for your DB script I think.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but looking at your Get class, it's generally bad practice to do things like setting your `$this->sql` in a `getSql()` call, and then relying on that with your `Query()`. It's always much better to be explicit about what your methods are doing with the name, and not relying on what are essentially hidden quirks on the inside. As an example, it would be a much better design if your `Query()` took the sql that you got from `getSql()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because you are not calling `parent::__construct()` in your overridden constructor and your database connection is never created.